# How quotes and cart work in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, cart, quote

Can anybody explain how quotes and cart work in magento? Where the cart or quote is assigned to customer? Are any events and which are doing that. I need to disable (assign) under certain conditions. I can create new quote, add product, update product and delete product until I want to proceed to checkot. Then my quote in table sales_flat_quote is updated by customer who in currently logged in.

Answer (score 9):

A quote is **cart** object, this quote is created when the customer adds the first product to the cart and its not created when the customer is created.

A customer can have many quotes. One for each website.

a quote is **not necessarily** assigned to a customer, the proof; you can have a quote as guest.

Quote is an **order** that hasn't been placed yet. It contains product items, when the user clicks place order, the **quote** is converted to an **order**.

Comment: One of the best theoretical answer I have seen on this community.